# how do you connect angular js to node js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

> This is my html file   Bootstrap
>   Example    
>   href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css">
>   
>   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
>
> // Get the modal var modal =
>   document.getElementById('myModal'); // Get the image and insert it
>   inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a         var img =
>   document.getElementById('myImg'); var modalImg =
>   document.getElementById("img01"); var captionText =
>   document.getElementById("caption"); img.onclick = function(){
>   modal.style.display = "block"; modalImg.src = this.src; modalImg.alt =
>   this.alt; captionText.innerHTML = this.alt; } // Get the 
>   element that closes the modal var span =
>   document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]; // When the user clicks
>   on  (x), close the modal span.onclick = function() {
>   modal.style.display = "none"; }   
>    
>  
>   
>     
>   
>   Toggle navigation     Home  
>     Cakes
>
> Pineapple
>
> whitecake
>
> fruitcake
>
> gift
>
> AllGIFTS
>
> SOFT TOYS
>
> Personalized gifts
>
> Flowers Combos
>
> ```
>    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
>     <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
>         <div class="item active">
>      <img src="63hB3f3.jpg" alt="Chania">
>      < div class="carousel-caption">
>     ...
>      </div>
>     </div>
>      <div class="item">
>       <img src="Whiteforest-Cake-6.jpg" alt="Chania">
>       <div class="carousel-caption">
>        ...
>      </div>
>     </div>
>      ...
>     </div>
>
>   <!-- Controls -->
>     <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-
>        generic"role="button" data-slide="prev">
>     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" 
>         aria-hidden="true">   </span>
>       <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
>          </a>
>      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example
>          -generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
>            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" 
>        aria-hidden="true"></span>
>       <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
>     </a>
>      </div>
>
>     <div class="row">
>         <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ">
>          <a href="greeting-card-large.jpg" class="thumbnail ">
>
>          <img id="myImg" src="greeting-card-large.jpg" 
>       alt="Pulpit Rock"     style="width:150px;height:150px" >
>
>
> </a>   </div>   <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
> <a href="G08-247x250.jpg" class="thumbnail ">
>
>   <img src="G08-247x250.jpg" alt="Moustiers Sainte Marie" style="width:150px;height:150px" id="G08-247x250.jpg">
>
>
>
> </a>   </div>   <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
> <a href="cpg159-247x250.jpg" class="thumbnail cake1">
>
>   <img src="cpg159-247x250.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" style="width:150px;height:150px" id="cpg159-247x250.jpg">
>
> </a>   </div>   <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
> <a href="choco-vanilla-cake-5.jpg" class="thumbnail cake2">
>
>   <img src="choco-vanilla-cake-5.jpg" alt="Pulpit Rock" style="width:150px;height:150px" id="choco-vanilla-cake-5.jpg">
>
> </a>   </div>   <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
> <a href="Whiteforest-Cake-6.jpg" class="thumbnail cake3">
>
>   <img src="Whiteforest-Cake-6.jpg" alt="Moustiers Sainte Marie" style="width:150px;height:150px" id="Whiteforest-Cake-6.jpg">
>
> </a>   </div>   <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
> <a href="Combo-deal-27.jpg" class="thumbnail combo1">
>
>   <img src="Combo-deal-27.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" style="width:150px;height:150px" id="Combo-deal-27.jpg">
>
> </a>   </div>   <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
> <a href="Combo-deal-22.jpg" class="thumbnail combo2">
>
>   <img src="Combo-deal-22.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" style="width:150px;height:150px" id="Combo-deal-22.jpg">
>
> </a>   </div>   <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
> <a href="Combo-deal-241.jpg" class="thumbnail combo3">
>
>   <img src="Combo-deal-241.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" style="width:150px;height:150px" id="Combo-deal-241.jpg">
>
> </a>   </div>
>  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
> <a href="heart-shape-cake-111.jpg" class="thumbnail cake4">
>
>   <img src="heart-shape-cake-111.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" style="width:150px;height:150px" id="heart-shape-cake-111.jpg">
>
> </a>   </div> </div> </div> </div> </body> </html>
> ```
>
> This is mysqldemo.js(node js file)
>
> var mysql=require('mysql'); var connection=mysql.createConnection({
>               host:'localhost',
>         user:'satheesh',
>         password:'muthyala@!1991',
>         database:'satheesh',
>         port:3306 });
>
> connection.connect(); var query=connection.query('select * from
>   details',function(err,result,fields){ if (err) throw err;
>   console.log('result:',result); }); connection.end();

Comment: Can you take some time to clean up/format you question? It is very difficult to read like this.

Comment: I have nodejs file in the local host which connects to mysql database. my sql database has cake table which contains name and price.I want to connect angular js to node js so that i can retrieve name and price from the cake table.